# React Native Promise <fulfilled>

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Why is it i cant get the token even the result is Promise fulfilled?

```
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const task = InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => 
      {
        const _token =  AsyncStorage.getItem('@token');
        setToken(_token);
        console.log("============================================", _token)
        GetFolderInformation(token, folderId)
        navigation.closeDrawer();
      });
      return () => task.cancel();
    }, [folderId])
  );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to await the `AsyncStorage.getItem('@token')`.

```js
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const task = InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(async () => {
        const _token =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token');
        setToken(_token);
        console.log("============================================", _token)
        GetFolderInformation(token, folderId)
        navigation.closeDrawer();
      });

      return () => task.cancel();
    }, [folderId])
  );
```